# Send argument in defined event function

Tags: c#, events, ip-address

I'm using `Ping` class from `System.Net.NetworkInformation` and I need to send some string data to event function for `PingCompleted` event handler.
ive tried this:

```
void ex_ping_PingCompleted(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e, string adress)
{

}
```

...

```
ex_ping.PingCompleted += (sender1, args) => ex_ping_PingCompleted(sender1, new 
PingCompletedEventArgs(), adress);
```

but it tells me that `PingCompletedEventArgs` has no constructor.
I've tried to make my own event args:

```
public class ProgressEventArgs : PingCompletedEventArgs
{
            public string adress;
            public ProgressEventArgs(string ex_adress)
            {
                adress = ex_adress;
            }
}
```

Same error here.
I just want to know what address I pinged, `e.Reply.Address` in event function gives me IP, I need the site name.

edit:
just figured it out by myself:

```
 ex_ping.PingCompleted += (sender1, args) => ex_ping_PingCompleted(sender1, args,adress); 

    void ex_ping_PingCompleted(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e,string ex_adress)        {
    }
```

works fine, /close

Answer (score 1):

Subscribe to event

```
 ex_ping.PingCompleted += ex_ping_PingCompleted;
```

And get address in handler

```
void ex_ping_PingCompleted(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   // verify if operation was not canceled or some error occured

   var address = e.Reply.Address;
   IPHostEntry entry = Dns.GetHostEntry(address);
   var siteName = entry.HostName;
}
```

Comment: it gives me ip, i need site name

Comment: @user2023489 added retrieving host name from ip

Comment: `if (e.Reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
                var address = e.Reply.Address;
                System.Net.IPHostEntry entry = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(address);
                var siteName = entry.HostName;
 }`
exception on GetHostEntry - unknown host

Comment: Exception type "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException" was raised in System.dll, but wasnt catch by user code
additional info: that host is unknown

Comment: @user2023489 that means DNS server does not have site name associated with your ip address

Comment: well, i pinged google.com. `string adress = "google.com";
            ex_ping.PingCompleted+=ex_ping_PingCompleted;
            ex_ping.SendAsync(adress, 500, buffer, options, adress);` that means i still need to get that adress in event function somehow. How can i do that? I need to send that string named 'adress' into event function

Answer (score 0):

You're after the `UserState` property:

```
void Ping()
{
    string address = "google.com";
    ex_ping.PingCompleted+=ex_ping_PingCompleted;
    ex_ping.SendAsync(address, 500, buffer, options, address);
}

void ex_ping_PingCompleted(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // Will give you the hostname
    var address = e.UserState;
}
```